# What is the earliest hook you can piggyback on to check terms/taxonomy for a collection view?

Tags: taxonomy, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I am attempting to set up some conditional logic based on whether or not `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' )` has the term 'Photographs' in it. Currently I'm using the `wp` hook, but that doesn't seem to run until the primary Query has already ran.. which I need to modify.

This has to be done because I basically need what appears to be two different front-end stores, but of course it needs to all be together in the back-end Woo admin.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the Codex [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) handy - while it doesn't list everything, it gives a good overview of action order which can help locate the correct action if the one you're using runs too late.

In your case, [`wp`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp) does indeed run after the query is run, but looking at that list it appears - depending exactly on what logic you're wanting to run - that [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) would be a good choice for you. This is actually a commonly used action that, quite powerfully, allows you to modify almost *anything* about the query before it runs.

Not seeing your code it's a little difficult to anticipate exactly what you want this to perform, but I am guessing you're after something like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse202063_photographs_term' );

function wpse202063_photographs_term( $query ){
  if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_singular( 'product' ) ){
    $post_object = get_page_by_path( $query->query['name'], 'OBJECT', 'product' );
    if( has_term( 'photographs', 'product_cat', $post_object ) ){
      // modify the query here as you need, using $query->set()
    }
  }
}
```

When you're viewing a single post of the post type 'product', this should allow you to modify the `$query` object to change whatever you need.<sup>1</sup>

It's important to note the snippet above is just preliminary - this might not be the *fastest* way to do what you want to do; it also assumes you're using pretty permalinks.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note that `pre_get_posts` passes `$query` [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so there is no need to globalise `$wp_query` to make your changes - you can just make them directly using `$query->set( 'query_var', 'value' );` - obviously replacing 'query_var' with the var you want to modify and the 'value' with what you want to set it to (you can use an array also).</sub>